# Why does my execution dissapear after modifying a local entity returned from Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Web API controller in ASP.Net Core MVC.

It looks like this:

```
namespace Hrsa.Core.Web.App.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CasesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IGenericService<Case> _caseGenericService;

        public CasesController(IGenericService<Case> caseGenericService)
        {
            _caseGenericService = caseGenericService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<Case> AddCase([FromBody] EmployeeCaseFromBodyModel model)
        {
            Case employeeCase = new Case()
            {
                InitalConsultDate = model.InitialConsultDate,
            };

            Case newCase = await _caseGenericService.InsertAsync(employeeCase);
            EmployeeCase empToCase = new EmployeeCase
            {
                CaseId = newCase.Id,
                EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId
            };
            newCase.EmployeeCases.Add(empToCase);
            await _caseGenericService.UpdateAsync(newCase);
            return newCase;
        }

    }
}
```

I get my new case back from the generic service.
And my new case has a newly generated id. Great.

Now I create a new EmployeeCase record with the id of my newly generated case and the employee id I want to add the case to.

Now I try to simply add the Employee case record into the EmployeeCases Collection.

But the execution just gets swallowed up and disappears.
I get a bunch of thread exited lines in the output window.

```
The thread 0x2128 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2e38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2658 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Once new case had been inserted and returned by Entity Framework, isn't the newCase variable a local variable?
Shouldn't I just be able to modify it like this?

Where is the execution going?
While debugging, when I step to the next line it just keeps giving me thread exited lines forever and never goes to the next line.

Could the entity still be attached to the dbContext somehow and not being let go?
Is that why it won't let me work with it locally?

I thought I could just modify it locally like this and then send the whole entity up for a update after adding the EmployeeCase record to it.
But it gets swallowed up before ever getting to the update line.

***UPDATE 1:***

Now I see in the output window before all of the "The thread nnn has exited with code 0" lines:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Hrsa.Core.Web.App.dll
```

So something is null in this line:

```
newCase.EmployeeCases.Add(empToCase);
```

But I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the EmployeeCases list of newCase was still null while I tried to add to the list.

I added this line:

```
newCase.EmployeeCases = new List<EmployeeCase>();
```

Complete HttpPost:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Case> AddCase([FromBody] EmployeeCaseFromBodyModel model)
    {
        Case employeeCase = new Case()
        {
            // LerSpecialistId = model.LerSpecialistId,
            // InitialContactId = model.InitialContactId,
            InitalConsultDate = model.InitialConsultDate,
            // Notes = model.Notes
        };

        Case newCase = await _caseGenericService.InsertAsync(employeeCase);

        newCase.EmployeeCases = new List<EmployeeCase>();
        newCase.EmployeeCases.Add(new EmployeeCase
            {
                CaseId = newCase.Id,
                EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId
            }
        );
        await _caseGenericService.UpdateAsync(newCase);
        return newCase;
    }
```